# Boost 1.54 install installing nothing

Tags: boost, compilation, mingw, installation

I've been trying to get boost to compile and install using MinGW (4.8.1) on Windows 7 x64.

It appears to bootstrap ok:

```
bootstrap.bat mingw
```

gives:

```
Building Boost.Build engine

Bootstrapping is done. To build, run:

    .\b2

To adjust configuration, edit 'project-config.jam'.
Further information:

    - Command line help:
    .\b2 --help

    - Getting started guide:
    http://boost.org/more/getting_started/windows.html

    - Boost.Build documentation:
    http://www.boost.org/boost-build2/doc/html/index.html
```

looks good. Then I try to build and install, using the following command:

```
b2 variant=release threading=multi toolset=gcc --with-date_time --with-filesystem
--with-iostreams --with-locale --with-program_options --with-regex --with-system
--with-thread --prefix=D:\boost install
```

but this just results in the unhelpful message:

```
...found 2 targets...
```

However, if I leave off the install option the libraries I require get built, but not installed. I've googled and googled and googled, but I just can't find any clues as to where I'm going wrong. In fact, everything out there appears to suggest the install option works just fine!

If I build, and then run the same again with the install option, I get the same "found 2 targets" reponse from b2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens for me, on Windows 7 64-bit when MinGW 4.8.1 is being used. If I replace MinGW 4.8.1 with mingw-w64 4.8.1 the process works fine.

There are no other changes to the environments I tested, only the different MinGW versions.

As it happens I want to move everything over to mingw-w64 to use sjlj exceptions anyway, so everything is good. No idea why it doesn't work under the "standard" mingw though.

Answer (score 1):

If you see the error of `...found 2 targets...` 
it means you have problem with the path/setup of gcc (MinGw). Just re-install MinGw on your system. I recommend using the same bit system as your processor is. Then set the path in System Environment to the bin folder which contains g++, make... files. Now you are ready to go.

1. For obvious reasons,  start a fresh terminal (cmd.exe), don't use the already open terminals that don't know your new setting.
2. Download boost, the latest stable release, unzip it and in the command window follow the path too the main directory of the extracted boost.
3. Run this command:
   `bootstrap mingw`
4. Run this command afterwards, which will install in the folder you select as your destination.

   b2 install --prefix=c:\boost\1.54.0\gcc toolset=gcc

It takes a while be patient :)